# React lazy loading javascript file

Tags: reactjs, import, export, lazy-loading

I am trying to make my application more performant with React.lazy. As the Ethereum lightwallet is a huge file, I would like to put it into a separate bundle. The currently working import is the following:

```
import lightwallet from 'eth-lightwallet/dist/lightwallet.min.js';
```

When I try to import using the lazy syntax

```
const lightwallet = React.lazy(() => import('eth-lightwallet/dist/lightwallet.min.js'));
```

Only a React.lazy object *($$typeof: Symbol(react.lazy))* is returned instead of the lightwallet object. I think this is due to the fact that lightwallet doesn't have a default export. How could I get around this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest following the example here:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting

`react-loadable` is an npm package that makes code-splitting (a.k.a lazy loading) quite easy and also provides you the ability to render a loading component until the lazy load has finished.

The only gotcha is that if you're using `Babel` to transpile your code bundles, you'll have to add support for the Dynamic Import syntax, `webpack` already has this by default, but `Babel` doesn't.

The Babel Plugin:
`@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`
will make this possible by adding support for the syntax.

I recommend `react-loadable` over `React.lazy` as it makes displaying a loading component while the lazy-load happens VERY easy, and provides you hooks to display an error component and retry the import in the case that it fails.

Read more about `react-loadable` here:
https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

Your code would look something like this:

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loading from './YOUR-LOADING-COMPONENT';

const LoadableWallet = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('eth-lightwallet/dist/lightwallet.min.js'),
  loading: Loading,
});

export default class Wallet extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableWallet/>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your react version is up to date in React v16.6.0. And also the core idea behind the React. lazy is React.lazy takes a function that must call a dynamic import(). This must return a **Promise** which resolves to a module with a **default export** containing a **React component**. But is this scenario min.js won't give any promise. Most probably That didn't work.

Comment: Also make sure your `react-dom` is v16.6