# lazy() loading not loading non component js file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I am trying to lazy load constant file in react. This constant file is not react component just simple javascript files like below :

```
// constant.js

export const customFunction = () => {
}
```

```
// component.js
const {
customFunction,
} = React.lazy(() => import('./constant.js'));
```

This I am not able to find in browser under developer tools source option. Also due to this getting `customFunction` undefined error. This code work if do normal import. `customFunction` using under `useEffect()`

```
import {
customFunction
} from './constant.js';
```

Comment: These are some related questions I found on stackoverflow, with answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756177/how-to-lazy-load-a-js-file-in-react-for-a-multilingual-app

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521727/react-lazy-loading-javascript-file

Comment: can you link here. I tried didn't found related this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do not wrap `import` statement inside `React.lazy`. Instead only use `import()` which returns a `Promise` and it gets resolved to the contents of the mentioned file

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-darkness-o4c2n)

Comment: I tried this but getting error " Couldn't load Custom Script  Error: Cannot find module './constant'

Comment: What is your react and react-dom version?

Comment: "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"

Comment: It is working in the example I mentioned. From your error, it seems that the path provided to the file wasn't correct. Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: I checked path because similar path is working for normal import. I see your example is working.

Comment: How and where are you calling "loadCustom"?
Where is "loadCustom" function is written?
Where is the "custom.js" file?
Keeping this example in mind.

Comment: `loadCustom` am calling before component after importing other files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237606/discussion-between-hamza-asif-and-aviboy2006).